# Trouble with creating the Scrabble board game using LibGDX

Tags: java, swing, libgdx, tiled

I'm new to game creation and just wanted to give it a shot. I decided to try and create Scrabble however I've run into a problem. I don't know how to represent the board in LibGDX and every letter a player has in their hands.

I made the game as a test using Swing in which I used a 2d array of buttons for the board, and buttons to represent the letters in each players hand. The user would click on a letter button, then on a board button and the letter would then be applied to the board. I've looked into Tiled to maybe create a tiled map but don't know how I would implement the letters each player has and how this would would interact with my validation class.

My validation class basically looks at the letters on the board and checks them with an arraylist of words to check for possible letter combinations that could make a word.If the word being spelt isn't valid the user can not end their turn until they fix it or pass.

If anyone has any insight into this I'd really appreciate it as I've looked online for tutorials or any help and I couldn't come across anything that assist me.

Comment: Hello and welcome on StackOverflow. Please note that Questions on this page should always include the relevant source code in order to allow more accurate answers.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please take the [Tour]

Comment: At least provide more details - not everyone around here played Scrabble.

Comment: @MilanG Scrabble is a word game in which two to four players score points by placing tiles bearing a single letter onto a board divided into a 15×15 grid of squares. The tiles must form words which, in crossword fashion, read left to right in rows or downwards in columns, and be defined in a standard dictionary or lexicon.